# When scrolling DIV Tooltip moves rapidly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am working on a project where I need to show a tree structure div. And on hover a Tooltip with image will show.

The problem is it is working fine on loading the page but if u scroll to right the Tooltip is going too much far from the original div.

Pls help me to fix the issue.

Im going to attach the screenshot for ref.

URL: http://howrahcitypolice.in/organizational-structure/?id=83

Comment: show us the code you are using to show the tool tip

Comment: `php javascript jquery html css` really! i am not able to see the code you have posted.

Comment: If you are adding the scroll position of the div while adding the tool tip remove this

Answer (score 0):

```
position:fixed;
top:5%;
left:30%;
```

Something like that?